# The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift in migration to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I have a project, I'm migrating it from Swift 2.3 to Swift 4 and when I build it on the device I have the above mentioned errors.

The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift 4:
/Carthage/Build/iOS/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
/Carthage/Checkouts/SwiftRecord/SwiftRecord.framework/SwiftRecord

How can I fix it !! Please help. Thanks

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]

Comment: I guess that https://github.com/arkverse/SwiftRecord doesn't support Swift 4, so you'll have an issue.